# Scala Slick incompatible with Kerberos?

Tags: scala, jdbc, kerberos, slick, playback

We have an `Scala Play` application, where its used both plain queries with jdbc and `Slick` ORM.

From 2 weeks, my team migrated all databases on Kerberos, so I was forced to update the connection settings. All good using `Connection` from `Java` for our plain queries, but encountered problems after updating connection string for Slick.

```
Encountered: STRING LITERAL
Expected: DEFAULT, IDENTIFIER

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
), Query: select "col1", "col2", "col3" from "tableName".
[^[[31merror^[[0m] d.d.s.ClassName- 1620996573139 - 
[Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. 
  Error Code: 0, SQL state: 
    TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:ParseException: 
      Syntax error in line 1: ...col", "col" from "tableName"
```

I copied the query generated by `Slick` and execute it. All columns are writen between quotation mark and the query results will contains only column names as values:

```
select "col1", "col2"
from "tableName"
limit 10;
```

results in:

```
col1, col2
col1, col2
col1, col2
```

Can be this the problem? And how I can specify to Slick to remove quotation marks from query, if is so?!

> le: I forgot to specify: is a Impala Kudu database

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After a minutious debug, I found that Slick throw a NonFatal error with the message: "`Cannot initialize ExecutionContext; AsyncExecutor already shut down`";

I can't understand why/what is that. Anyway, I rennounced at slick and wrote plain sql using jdbc to execute it.